# how to duplicate pdf page

Tags: delphi, pdf

There is a source file pdf.  I need to transfer the contents of the page to another file. I use the LitePDF library:

```
SrcPDF := TLitePDF.Create;
SrcPDF.LoadFromFile(FList[PagesManager.List[i].FileIndex].Name, '', True);
PageRes := ResPDF.PageToResource(PagesManager.List[i].PageNo - 1);
SrcPDF.DrawResource(PageRes, 0 , LitePDFUnit_mm, 0, 0 , 200, 200);
ResPDF.FinishPage(PDFPage);

SrcPDF.Free;
SourcePDF.Free;
```

On DrawResource crreate exception
litePDF_DrawResource: Resource ID is out of range.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please, provide a [mre].

Answer (score 1):

Task complete.

```
SrcPDF := TGALitePDF.Create;
SrcPDF.LoadFromFile(FList[PagesManager.List[i].FileIndex].Name, '', True, True);
if PagesManager.List[i].Rotate then
  SrcPDF.RotatePage(PagesManager.List[i].PageNo); //its myself procedure
PageRes := ResPDF.AddPageFromAsResource(SrcPDF, PagesManager.List[i].PageNo);
ResPDF.DrawResource(PageRes, 0, LitePDFUnit_mm, PagesManager.List[i].X + Margins.Left, PagesManager.List[i].Y + Margins.Top, 1, 1);
SrcPDF.Free;
```